# Generate a javascript table from bootstrap tabs

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to generate js tables when tabs are selected. Each tab will generate a different table. The tables never shows up. I'm not tied to bootstrap tabs so if there is a different solution outside of bootstrap tabs I'm perfectly fine with that.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
 <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
 <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
 <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
 <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
  <script type="text/javascript">table1()</script>
 </div>
 <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
  <script type="text/javascript">table2()</script>
 </div>
 <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
  <script type="text/javascript">table3()</script>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to complete the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the help topic [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting. Good questions normally have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, StackOverflow has an [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) with lots of information. Thanks.

Comment: SO is for solving problems found in programming. But you have to write the code first. Try something and return here with your problem. We will be happy to help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

For something like this you could just use some jquery and roll your own code. Try this.

```
$('.nav-tabs li').on('click', function() {
    $('.tab-pane').hide().eq($(this).index()).show();
});
```

Here you just click the menu item and it will show the corresponding content. You can also use an `if/else` here to choose which function you'd like to fire depending on which menu item you clicked. Hope that can give you a push in the right direction.

http://jsfiddle.net/fzc3opv2/

```js
$('.nav-tabs li').on('click', function() {
  var index = $(this).index();
  $('.tab-pane').hide().eq(index).show();
  
  if (index === 0) {
    //table1();
    console.log('Run function 1.');
  } else if (index === 1) {
    //table2();
    console.log('Run function 2.');
  } else {
    //table3();
    console.log('Run function 3.');
  }
});
```

```css
.nav-tabs {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
}

.tab-content {
  background: #4c4c4c;
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

.tab-pane {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
 <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
 <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
 <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
 <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
   <p>Menu 1</p>
 </div>
 <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade hide">
   <p>Menu 2</p>
 </div>
 <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade hide">
   <p>Menu 3</p>
 </div>
</div>
```